# PHP Character Encoding Error: How they do it?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

Problem:

I have a Textarea, that except XML as content and post to server. It works fine if all Ascii characters are there, but when we put data in hebrew then `simplexml_load_string` fail to load the data, prompting that invalid XML as data encoding breaks the data been posted.

What I did:

1. I have my HTML meta tag for UTF-8 is set, I do have php `header` set for content to be `UTF-8`
2. I have MySQL set to `'SET NAMES utf8`.
3. When `print_r(iconv_get_encoding('all'));` it print all three values as `ISO-8859-1`.
4. When I print `$_POST` it shows hebrew characters fine on browser [on Browser view source as well], but still the function failed.
5. When I change php.ini to take iconv encoding as UTF-8 all works fine again.

However:
Same server does have 100s of Wordpress installation that run Hebrew website, and they don't have such problem.

So, my question is: Why my code is failing but wordpress or any other open source software works just fine with encoding. I did try to set iconv to utf-8 as first executable line, but nothing changed for me.

Not sure I explain my problem fine and my question is clear, if not please let me know. Thanks.

EDIT: I did try `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` function but they too failed.

Comment: Did you take a look at: mb_internal_encoding

Comment: if you mean `mbstring.internal_encoding` then it has novalue [I think that is default value ?]

Comment: @colburton also, even whatever it is set, same domain runs wordpress fine with hebrew and same PHP setting as my custom code.

Comment: I just set `mb_internal_encoding()` to `UTF-8` but still doesn't load XML.

Comment: on testing afresh it seems your suggested `mb_internal_encoding` does solve the issue, Thanks @colburton, maybe you post it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` to tell php what encoding you are using. With this you are overwriting the settings from php.ini.